# Update chart properties in Open XML

Tags: c#, openxml

I am recently trying to create a bar chart in excel using Open XML and C#.

Below is portion of the script that helped me to create a bar chart in excel.

```
 // Add a new drawing to the worksheet.
DrawingsPart drawingsPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Drawing() { Id = worksheetPart.GetIdOfPart(drawingsPart) });
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

// Add a new chart and set the chart language to English-US.
ChartPart chartPart = drawingsPart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>();
chartPart.ChartSpace = new ChartSpace();
chartPart.ChartSpace.Append(new EditingLanguage() { Val = new StringValue("en-US") });
Drawing.Charts.Chart chart = chartPart.ChartSpace.AppendChild<Drawing.Charts.Chart>(new Drawing.Charts.Chart());
addChartTitle(chart, chartTitleText);

// Create a new clustered column chart.
PlotArea plotArea = chart.AppendChild<PlotArea>(new PlotArea());
Layout layout = plotArea.AppendChild<Layout>(new Layout());
addBarchart(plotArea);
addCategoryAxis(plotArea);

// Add the Value Axis.
ValueAxis valAx = plotArea.AppendChild<ValueAxis>(new ValueAxis(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768u) },
    new Scaling(new Orientation() { Val = new EnumValue<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues>(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax) }),
    new AxisPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<AxisPositionValues>(AxisPositionValues.Left) }, new MajorGridlines(), new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.NumberingFormat()
    { FormatCode = new StringValue("General"), SourceLinked = new BooleanValue(true) }, new TickLabelPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<TickLabelPositionValues> (TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo) },
    new CrossingAxis() { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112U) }, new Crosses() { Val = new EnumValue<CrossesValues>(CrossesValues.AutoZero) }, new CrossBetween() { Val = new EnumValue<CrossBetweenValues>(CrossBetweenValues.Between) }));
```

But unfortunately when I tried to edit the colors of bars, I couldn't make it successful. Please help me create a chart and to update chart properties using Open XML and C#.

Comment: In order to help you, we need the see the excel file and then we need the code where you tried to change the colors.  The code above is nice as a reference, but if you can't post the problem code that did not work, and any errors you encountered, its very hard to try fix your problem.  Show us what you tried.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. i could get my things fixed properly. will be back if i need some other help